# Show that $\phi$ is surjective in commutative staircase diagram

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, diagram-chasing

I'm having some trouble with the following problem involving a sort of staircase diagram and I would really appreciate some help.

Assume the following commutative diagram of modules and module morphisms has exact rows and columns:

[image]

Show that $\phi$ is surjective.

---

Here is what I have so far:

- Let some $y\in H_4$ be given. Since the diagram has exact rows, $\psi_3$ is surjective so there exists some $u\in L_3$ with $\psi_3(u)=\alpha_4(y)$.
- Since the diagram is commutative and since $\text{im}(\alpha_4)=\text{ker}(\beta_4)$,
  $$\chi_3(\beta_3(u)) = \beta_4(\psi_3(u)) = \beta_4(\alpha_4(u)) = 0$$
  so $\beta_3(u) \in \text{ker}(\chi_3) = \text{im}(\chi_2)$. Let $v\in M_2$ be such that $\chi_2(v)=\beta_3(u)$.
- Again we have
  $$\eta_2(\gamma_2(v)) = \gamma_3(\chi_2(v))=\gamma_3(\beta_3(u))=0$$
  so $\gamma_2(v)\in \text{ker}(\eta_2) = \text{im}(\eta_1)$. Let $w\in N_1$ be such that $\eta_1(w) = \gamma_2(v)$
- Since $\gamma_1$ is surjective, there exists some $a\in M_1$ with $\gamma_1(a) = w$.

This is where I get stuck. I think I somehow need to use all this to swim back up the diagram but I can't figure out how. I also had a thought that if $\phi(x)=y$ then
$$\alpha_4(y)=\alpha_4(\phi(x))=\psi_3(\alpha_3(x))$$
so it would be sufficient to find some $x$ such that $\psi_3(\alpha_3(x))=\alpha_4(y)$ since $\alpha_4$ is injective, however, I haven't figured out if this is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your proof (with different notation) we have the following elements:

- $h_4\in H_4$
- $\ell_4\in L_4$ such that $\ell_4=\alpha_4(h_4)$
- $\ell_3\in L_3$ such that $\ell_4=\psi_3(\ell_3)$
- $m_3\in M_3$ such that $m_3=\beta_3(\ell_3)$
- $m_2\in M_2$ such that $m_3=\chi_2(m_2)$
- $n_2\in N_2$ such that $n_2=\gamma_2(m_2)$
- $n_1\in N_1$ such that $n_2=\eta_1(n_1)$
- $m_1\in M_1$ such that $n_1=\gamma_1(n_1)$
- $\ell_2\in L_2$ such that $m_2-\chi_1(m_1)=\beta_2(\ell_2)$
- $h_3\in H_3$ such that $\ell_3-\psi_2(\ell_2)=\alpha_3(h_3)$

Then we have:
\begin{align}
(\alpha_4\circ\phi)(h_3)
&=(\psi_3\circ\alpha_3)(h_3)\\
&=\psi_3(\ell_3-\psi_2(\ell_2))\\
&=\ell_4-(\psi_3\circ\psi_2)(\ell_2)\\
&=\ell_4\\
&=\alpha_4(h_4)
\end{align}
from which $\phi(h_3)=h_4$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just for clarification for future viewers:

We have
\begin{align}
\gamma_2(m_2-\chi_1(m_1)) &= \gamma_2(m_2)-\gamma_2(\chi_1(m_1)) \\
&=n_2-\eta_1(\gamma_1(m_1)) \\
&=n_2-\eta_1(n_1) \\
&= n_2-n_2\\
&= 0
\end{align}
so $m_2-\chi_1(m_1)\in \text{ker}(\gamma_2) = \text{im}(\beta_2)$ so we can find an element $l_2$ of $L_2$ with $\beta_2(l_2)=m_2-\chi_1(m_1)$.

The justification for $h_3$ is similar.